# Will this universal save to cloudkit function work? It tries to save anyObject which is determined by context

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am creating an app that will require a lot of saving and loading in CloudKit, so I had to create a database class that will make some code reusable. On of the functions in it is this:

```
func save(fieldsWithValues: [String: Any], inRecordType: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool , NSError?) -> Void) {
    let recordID = CKRecordID(recordName: inRecordType)
    publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: recordID) { record, error in
        guard let record = record else {
            //handle errors here
            return
        }
        for fieldWithValue in fieldsWithValues {
            record[fieldWithValue.key] = fieldWithValue.value as? CKRecordValue
        }
        self.publicDatabase.save(record) { _, error in
            if error == nil {
                completionHandler(true, nil)
            } else {
                completionHandler(false,error as NSError?)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is, will it work?